# Need help in Django Orm query

Tags: python, php, django, database, django-models

I have 3 models and they are as follow

```
class Table(models.Model):
   waiter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                                          related_name='restaurant_table')
   table_no = models.IntegerField()

   objects = TableManager()


class Order(models.Model):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   food = models.ManyToManyField(OrderFood, related_name='ordered_food')
   order_status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    CHOOSE = (
        ('Received', 'Received'),
        ('Cooking', 'Cooking'),
        ('WaiterHand', 'In Waiter Hand'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('Paid', 'Payment Completed'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False, choices=CHOOSE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Actually I am creating a restaurant management system. So here a restaurant has tables associated with a or more waiter. But I need a new feature that is table status. I mean when an order is actively associated with the table that means that table is booked. Actually that is not a problem as I can do that in many ways.

One way is I will count the active order associated with this table and if I found any active order I will return the table is booked.

Another way is I will add an extra field with the table that is a flag. This flag store status of tables is booked or not I mean the boolean field.

But my question is not the solution. My question which one is better or there are any other good solutions. Please explain it briefly I want to know which solution is better and why.

Comment: you're basically asking which of the ideas that you have is better.  Between "count active order and if one exists, table is booked"   or "have a boolean flag to mark that the table is booked".  what is your definition of 'better'?  have you tried either solutions?

Comment: Yup, I tried both solutions. Actually there was an argument with my teammate like which one should we use. He said that if we use "count active order and if one exists, the table is booked"  this approach then we don't need to write a table field where another is needed to write the field time to time. But I said that if we use 2nd approach which means "Adding a flag field" we don't need Join query or counting something. We can know the table status by the table id only. @ewong

Comment: Do you need a separate `OrderStatus` model? Can't hose fields just be added to the `Order` model? Using a `ForeignKey` suggests that the same `OrderStatus` could be linked to multiple `Order`s

Comment: @Almabud the issue with the first one is that what if the customers haven't ordered anything yet; but they're sitting at the table?

Comment: @lain Shelvington OrderStats can be added to the Order model. But I got the project with this model. :(

Comment: @ewong The requirement is when a waiter verified an order that time table status are gonna be booked. So if anyone just sitting at the table system will defined that table as unbooked

Comment: @Almabud are you in a position to change the models? You can write a migration to move the data to the new fields

Comment: @Lain Shelvington Yup I can do that but I need to inform the project leader. :(

Comment: @Lain Shelvington  I don't know maybe client requirement was that status will be dynamic, not static though it is now static or maybe they just apply simple normalization for that they introduce a new model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put `@property` function under `class Table` which you can use directly with any table objects, in templates also.

```
@property
def check_table_status(self):
    status = 'Not Booked'
    if self.order_set.all().exists():
        status = 'Booked'
    return status
```

Comment: Thank you @Pruthvi Barot this is also a nicer solution. And I think I am gonna apply it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Purthivi Barot -> whenever I am gonna print it throughout loop in the template don't you think that self.order_set.all().exists() this query will execute n times?

Comment: If you are sure that no orders can be without table then this will not necessary you can check this at one go

Comment: but yes it'll call this function each time called in the template, since it will check only existence of record it will minimal